# Remove A Part Of A String C# (FileName)

Tags: c#, string, substring

**The Question:**

I have files with time stamp added to their names, like this :

> "presentation final project_20141207182834657.pptx"

And

> "presentation final project_201412071864035.pptx"

How can I remove the "_date" part from it ?

Notice that i cant count char because sometimes the date is 15 char' and sometimes more, I need somehow to remove a part of the string that start with "_20" until it reach the "." (dot) or maybe someone got a better idea.

**Background:**

I have a storage of files, before I upload a file I give it a time stamp like this :

(JavaScript)

```
function getDate() {
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear().toString();
var month = (today.getMonth()+1).toString();
var day = today.getDate();

if (day < 10)
    day = "0" + day.toString();
else
    day = day.toString();

var hours = today.getHours().toString();
var minutes = today.getMinutes().toString();
var seconds = today.getSeconds().toString();
var miliSecond = today.getMilliseconds().toString();


return year+month+day+hours+minutes+seconds+miliSecond;
}
```

And what is return from this function I added to the file name.

Now I want to return the file to the user but without the date stamp i added to the file..

Thank you.

**Update**

Let me give a wild scenario, there is underscore "_" not only before the date like this :

> "presentation_final_project_201412071864035.pptx"

I cant trust the index of "_" because its can be everywhere.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: So would your expected output look like "presentation final project.pptx"?

Comment: Start from the right hand end of the string and find the first `_`. Then remove the text between there and the `.`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not just between - the `_` must be removed too

Comment: @fubo I think the asker will understand that, don't you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sure, the asker knew that answer without your trivial comment

Comment: @fubo Apparently the asker did not know that. Hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly trivial. Find the positions of the characters and build a new string using `Substring()`:

```
string input = "presentation final project_20141207182834657.pptx";

int underscoreIndex = input.LastIndexOf("_");
int dotIndex = input.LastIndexOf(".");

string newFilename = input.Substring(0, underscoreIndex);
newFilename += input.Substring(dotIndex);
```

See it in action on [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Cwq5B8).

Comment: Let me give a wild scenario, there is underscore "_" not only before the date like this :

> "presentation_final_project_201412071864035.pptx"

I cant trust the index of "_" because its can be everywhere.

Comment: @Ron Read the answer please. CodeCaster uses `LastIndexOf`. Also, wouldn't it have been better to give precise specifications of the form of the input in the question?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Your answer is okay as far as I am concerned. Do you know the performance difference between `Remove` (in my answer) and `Substring` concatenation in your answer? Shouldn't be that much I think. +1

Comment: @Patrick yeah you can as well use `input.Remove(underscoreIndex, dotIndex - underscoreIndex);`. Don't know about the performance difference.

Answer (score 3):

To extract the file parts I would use the Path class method to be more OS independent

```
string input = "presentation final project_20141207182834657.pptx";
string pureFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(input);
string ext = Path.GetExtension(input);
int pos = pureFile.LastIndexOf('_');
string newFile = pureFile.Substring(0, pos) +  ext;
```

Notice, to find the underscore you need to start from the end of the input string, not from the start to avoid false positives (in an underscore is present before the last one)

The only point left to uncertainty is the presence of the underscore, before or after the date part. If you can be sure that there is always an underscore just before the date and no underscore after the date this approach would work flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`string.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`string.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the text out:

```
string text = "presentation final project_20141207182834657.pptx";

int indexOfUnderscore = text.LastIndexOf('_'); // find the position of _
int indexOfPeriod = text.LastIndexOf('.', indexOfUnderscore); // find the position of .

// find remove the text between _ and .
string newText = text.Remove(indexOfUnderscore, indexOfPeriod - indexOfUnderscore);
```

Comment: Consider this input: `"presentation_final_project_20141207182834657.pptx"` Or perhaps this input: `"presentation_final_pro.ject_20141207182834657.pptx"`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: True, `LastIndexOf` would solve that, as in the revised answer. There would also be a problem if the file name was `presentation final project_20141207182834657_abc.pptx`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Why not. It works for the text OP has given and your additional requirement. Any pointers what is left?

Comment: The remaining references to and uses of `IndexOf`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I am not sure if that one has to go, but okay. I don't think it will matter a lot.

Comment: The file extension is best found with `LastIndexOf`. OK, that last edit gets it I think. DV removed. Thx.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Unless the extension is `.csproj.user` for example.

Comment: The extension is the text to the right of the final `.` in a string. So, `foo.bar.txt` has extension `.txt`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I know, but in string replacing, do you prefer to end up with `a.csproj.user` or `a.user`, although technically it isn't part of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

string r = "presentation final project_2011207182834657.pptx";

```
        string part1 = r.Substring(0, r.IndexOf(@"_"));

        string part2 = r.Substring(r.IndexOf(@"."), 5);

        Console.WriteLine(part1);

        Console.WriteLine(part2);

        Console.WriteLine(part1 + part2);
```

Answer (score -1):

here is a regex solution

```
string file = "presentation final project_201412071864035.pptx";
var result = Regex.Replace(file, @"(.*)(_[\d]{15,})(.*)$", "$1$3");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string oldpath = "presentation_final_project_201412071864035.pptx";
string date = oldpath.Split('_').LastOrDefault().Split('.').FirstOrDefault();
string newpath = oldpath.Replace("_" + date, "");
```

Comment: The OP wants the file without the date part, not the date part